# Performance issue in R Code

Tags: r, shiny

We have a set of 5000 KYC files in txt format. I need to perform NER on them , summarize the report in a form of table in shiny app which can be used in our website. However the parsing of files is taking a lot of time more than 30 minutes :(. Optmization needs to be done. Can any body suggest some methods that I need to implement. The text  file is in this format .

Name - XYZ
 Father Name - abc
 Address - mall road, shimla , India
 marital status - married
 Annual income - Rs 750000 
 Employed - Yes
 Guaranter - Mr def
 Credit Analyst Comments - XYZ  has no credit history. Might be a NPA in future.............
and other details

Steps involved:
1. Preprocessing the filename.(removal of numbers , spaces,since it is uploaded as a pdf and then converted to text from a site )

2. Creating indexes of all columns ( Name, Father Name,Address, marital status,annual income, age, credit analyst comments)
3. a function to parse each file. Used Named Entity Recognition and other techniques  to fetch keywords and ignore other words and map it to respective columns. the name of the fucntion is parseAKYC(file).
4. Called this function in another function parseallKYC.
5. The function parseallKYC(files_path)  is taking too much time to finish when there are a large set of files .With six files it gives me results in seconds.Want to use package parallel. Can anyone help me out ? Most of the examples shown are for sapply, lapply . Can we use package parallel for implementing my defined  function parseAllKYC  parallely ?
6. Here is the code for final function parseallKYC as shown below .

   `

   ```
   #code for parallel parsing 
   library(foreach) 
   library(iterators)
   library(doParallel)
   fileloc <- "location of 5000 KYC files"
   filelist <- list.files(path=fileloc,pattern = 'txt')
   files <- ""
   for (j in (1:length(filelist)))
   {
     files[j] <- paste0(fileloc,'/',filelist[j])
   }
   no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
   cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
   registerDoParallel(cl)
   KYCTable <- foreach(i=iter(files),.combine=rbind) %dopar% 
   {
     resume <- parseAKYC(i)
   }
   stopCluster(cl)

   #code for parseAKYC function
   require("NLP")
   require("openNLPmodels.en")
   require("openNLP")
   library(tm)
   library(DT)

   preprocessFile <- function(file) {
     file <- file[!duplicated(file)]
     file <- gsub("\\f", "", file)
     file <- gsub('""', "", file)
     file <- gsub("Page\\d+", "", file) 
     file <- gsub("-+", "", file)
     file <- file[file != ""]
     return (file)
   }
   extract_People_Location_Org <- function(file) {
     file <- lapply(file, removePunctuation)
     file <- unlist(file)
     s <- as.String(file)
     sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
     gc()
     word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
     a2 <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))

     ## Entity recognition for pepple's names.
     entity_annotator_people <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator()
     annotate(s, entity_annotator_people, a2)
     if (length(entity_annotator_people(s, a2)) == 0) {
       people_name <- ""
     } else {
       people_name <- s[entity_annotator_people(s, a2)]
     }
     if (length(people_name) > 1) {
       people_name <- people_name[!duplicated(people_name)]
     }
     result1 <- paste(people_name, collapse = ", ")

     ## Entity recognition for Location
     entity_annotator_location <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(kind =   "location")
     annotate(s, entity_annotator_location, a2)
     ## Directly:
     if (length(entity_annotator_location(s, a2)) == 0) {
       location <- ""
     } else {
       location <- s[entity_annotator_location(s, a2)]
     }
     if (length(location) > 1) {
       location <- location[!duplicated(location)]
     }
     result2 <- paste(location, collapse = ", ")

     ## Entity recognition for Organization
     entity_annotator_org <- Maxent_Entity_Annotator(kind = "organization")
     annotate(s, entity_annotator_org, a2)
     if (length(entity_annotator_org(s, a2)) == 0) {
       org <- ""
     } else {
       org <- s[entity_annotator_org(s, a2)]
     }
     if (length(org) > 1) {
       org <- org[!duplicated(org)]
     }

     result3 <- paste(org, collapse = ", ")
     return (c(result1, result2, result3))
   }
   extractCreditAnalystComments <- function(file) {
     index <- makeIndex(file)
     CreditAnalystComments <- paste(if (length(which(index == 6)) > 0) file[(which(index == 6)[1] + 1) : (tail(which(index == 6), 1))], collapse = ", ")
     return (paste(CreditAnalystComments, collapse = ", "))
   }
   makeIndex <- function(file) {
     # create a blank vector to store index of respective field
     # CODE: 1-Name 2-Job 3-Email 4-Language 5-Education 6-CreditAnalystCommentss (CreditAnalystCommentss & Expertise) 
     #       7-Experience (Experience, Volunteer Experience, Certifications)
     #       8-Summary 9-Interests  10-Certifications

     index <- rep(0, length(file))
     index[which(file == "Name")] <- 1
     index[which(file == "Address")] <- 2
     # index[which(grepl("@", file) == T)] <- 3
     index[which(file == "Marital Status")] <- 4
     index[which(file == "Annual Income")] <- 5
     index[which(file == "Employed")] <- 6
     index[which(file == "Guaranter")] <- 7
     index[which(file == "CreditAnalystComments")] <- 8
     index[which(file == "Interests")] <- 9
     index[which(file == "Credit History")] <- 10

     for (i in 1:(length(index)-1)) {
       if (index[i+1] == 0) {
         index[i+1] <- index[i]
       }
     }
     return (index)
   }
   parseAKYC <- function(file_name) {
     # input: a KYC in format *.txt


     # read file text
     file <- readLines(file_name, warn = F)

     # preprocessing file 
     file <- preprocessFile(file)

     KYC <- as.list(c("Name" = character(), "CreditAnalystComments" = character(), "Employed" = character(), 
                 "Address" = character(), "Annual Income" = character(), 
                 "Guaranter" = character()))
     KYC$Name <- file[1]
     KYC$CreditAnalystComments <- extractCreditAnalystComments(file)
     x <- extract_People_Location_Org(file)
     # -------------------------------------------------------------

     CreditAnalystComments.split <- unlist(strsplit(KYC$CreditAnalystComments, split = ","))
     CreditAnalystComments.split <- gsub("^\\s+", "", CreditAnalystComments.split)
     Employed.split <- unlist(strsplit(x[3], split = ","))
     Employed.split <- gsub("^\\s+", "", Employed.split)
     Employed_not_in_credit <- Employed.split[-which(Employed.split %in% CreditAnalystComments.split)]
     Employed<- paste0(Employed_not_in_CreditAnalystComments, collapse = ", ")
     # -------------------------------------------------------------

     # -------------------------------------------------------------

     Guaranter.split <- unlist(strsplit(x[1], split = ","))
     Guaranter.split <- gsub("^\\s+", "", Guaranter.split)
     Guaranter_not_in_CreditAnalystComments <- Guaranter.split[-which(Guaranter.split %in% CreditAnalystComments.split)]
     Guaranter <- paste0(Guaranter_not_in_CreditAnalystComments, collapse = ", ")
     # -------------------------------------------------------------

     KYC$Employed <- Employed
     # remember to change Java heap size memory to at leats 2GB
     KYC$Address <- x[2]
     #KYC$Designation <- file[2]
     KYC$Guaranter <- Guaranter
     return (as.data.frame(KYC, stringsAsFactors = F))
   }
       parseAllKYC <- function(files_path) {
             KYC .df <- data.frame(Name = character(),  FatherName = character(),   
                          Address = character(), maritalstatus = character(),  
                          Annualincome = character(),  
                          CreditAnalystComments= character(),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

             for (i in files_path) {
               KYC <- parseAKYC(i)
               KYC.df <- rbind(KYC.df, KYC)
             }
             return (KYC.df)
           }





            #ui.R

           fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'))))




                #server.R
                   library(shiny)
                   library(DT)
                   source("getKYCTable.R")
                   function(input, output, session)
                   {
                     output$tbl =DT::renderDataTable(KYCTable ,filter ='top',options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
                     )
                   }




       `
   ```

Comment: Do you want to run the code on multiple cores?

Comment: yes ..tried that . getting an error.  Here is the code used.

Comment: Can you make sure that you indent your code (parseAllKYC) properly. Also, I don't see parseAResume in your parseAllKYC function.

Comment: I did try that . Used CTRL+K  not working ..... Sorry . It's parseAKYC function only. Thank you for pointing out .

Comment: @Tushar , do you want me to paste the parseAKYC function? .

Comment: Are you working on ubuntu or windows machine??

Comment: You should also paste the parseAKYC function in a clear way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Although I think there could be optimization issue within your parseAKYC function, but to get you going you can parallelise in the following manner. This is for ubuntu setup. For windows you can check out the doSNOW package.

Use the following packages:

```
require(doParallel)
require(foreach)
require(doMC) #for ubuntu
require(doSNOW) #for windows

registerDoMC(cores = 4) #set value based on the number of cores  
                        #on your machine
#assuming file_path is a character vector of complete file paths.
parsed.output <- foreach(i=1:length(files_path)) %dopar%  parseAKYC(files_path[i])
```

Comment: I have added the parseAKYC function .  Implemented the parallel code but it throws an Error "could not find function "as.String""

Comment: in the function "extract_People_Location_Org ", you are using as.String function. 3rd line: s <- as.String(file), i think you should use, as.character()

Comment: that is a function in NLP . I converted to as.character. It is not allowing many functions like lapply(file, removePunctuation),unlist(file). I can't remove those. Can you suggest some good package for NLP parallel processing. Thanks in advance. You have been a great help.

Comment: I think you need to make changes to your code/design your functions such that you are able to run the entire parseAKYC, using for loop for each file and then replace for with foreach. Also, lapply and unlist not working is strange...could be that the inputs are not expected.You need to check that.

Comment: This code is perfectly working fine when I am not applying any parallel functions. So that is not the issue. Saw another post where NLP has its own version of parallel processing working on that. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Could you please share that post? Thanks.